# Building a not so basic photo slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, photo

beginner at programming and teaching myself javascript. I have managed to build a basic photo slider so far that changes pictures when you click on a "next" or previous button. Pretty basic stuff. Here is my code:

js:

```
var imageCount = 1;


function change(x)  {
    imageCount = imageCount + x;
    if(imageCount < 1)  {
        imageCount = 1;
        return;
    } else if (imageCount > 12) {
        imageCount = 12;
        return;
    }
    var image = document.getElementById('front');
    var str1 = "Images/01Pictures/Image";
    var str2 = imageCount;
    var str3 = ".jpg"
    var sum = str1.concat(str2, str3);

    image.src = sum;
```

And that works, although it's pretty static. Now I would like to attempt something much more ambitious. Something like this:

[image]

Which involves a lot of different things that I don't know anything about. The images being separated by white space and sliding on hover, the main picture getting bigger etc...
Since I am fairly new, I don't know where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Either a tutorial, or just a couple of ideas on the things I need to learn to be able to do this. I wouldn't want the code to do it as I want to learn by doing it, but I need a bit of guidance. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start with w3school at this link: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp

As well, it is good to have some knowledge about css animations. 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

That should be a good start. good luck!

Comment: Thank you this is helpful. The main thing I need help with is the scrolling images that go "off" screen and move to the centre on hover.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial seems to be what you are looking for:

https://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/